# C# anonymous function inside lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

I'm trying to work out the syntax for using an anonymous function inside the lambda of a linq .Where() call.

I'm using the Where to filter certain items from a list.

I want each part of the filter logic inside the Where.  The logic is only useful inside the filter so I don't want to have to define any functions outside.

Here's a simplified & generalised example:

```
var filtered = myEnumerable.Where(item =>
    item.PropertyA == 1 ||
    item.PropertyB == 2 ||
    item => 
    {
        var heavyResult = GetStuff(item); // Some heavyweight processing
        return heavyResult.IsSomethingTrue() && heavyResult.IsSomethingElseTrue();
    });
```

So I want the third line in the Where() to be an anonymous function taking item and returning a boolean.

Also, the function being called after the checks on PropertyA and PropertyB is intended to limit having to call GetStuff() if either of those lightweight comparisons already evaluated as true.

I can't do it all inline because I need to evaluate two properties from heavyResult.

This seems like it should be simple, but I don't seem to be able to find the right syntax, either by experimenting or Googling.

Comment: I am actually skeptical whether this is real scenario? You can do it in simpler numerous ways

Comment: While you could do this I doubt you *should*, as it just adds the need to document what exactly the function does. Instead just extract a named method that has an descriptive name to identify what happens within that method.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't do it all inline because I need to evaluate two properties from heavyResult.

You can do it inline, its just you need to wrap the entire thing in `{}` and use the `return` keyword.

```
var filtered = myEnumerable.Where(item =>
    {
        var test = item.PropertyA == 1 || item.PropertyB == 2;
        if(test)
          return true; 
        var heavyResult = GetStuff(item); // Some heavyweight processing
        return heavyResult.IsSomethingTrue() && heavyResult.IsSomethingElseTrue();
    });
```

To be honest though - doing something that even that simple inline is probably the wrong choice. Extract it into a function, with a meaningful name, and your code is self documenting

```
var filtered = myEnumerable.Where(ADescriptiveNamedFunctionSelfDocumentsYourCode);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did get it working with this style.  It just looks uglier to me for the PropertyA and PropertyB checks.   It seems there should be a way to bundle the GetStuff/heavyResult part into an anonymous function.

Comment: @Tom - there is. Its in this answer.

Comment: Thanks all.  I appreciate the comments regarding should I try to do it that way, and I think in my real example I will have to define an external method to do the filtering logic.

In terms of my specific question above, and purely syntactically speaking, I guess the answer is - no, there is not a way to define an anonymous function inline like that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, multiline lambdas are a really bad idea.

They were intended as simple functional representations `f(x)= ...` stuff.

You can't do this the way you're thinking because you first want to call a function, capture its result, & then call 2 different methods on that object.

You can do this more simply by moving the delegate out of the lambda.

The latest version of C# supports local functions, which may be what you want. But you can still do this with anonymous functions in C# 6.

I've also shown how you can do this with another method in `HeavyResult` or an extension method it's not feasible to change `HeavyResult`.

In the code below, you would use only one of the options from

```
validator(item) ||
GetStuff(item).IsAllTrue() ||
GetStuff(item).IsAllTrueExt()
```

Here's the full code:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myEnumerable = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        Predicate<int> validator;
        validator = delegate (int item)
        {
            var heavyResult = GetStuff(item);
            return heavyResult.IsSomethingTrue() && heavyResult.IsSomethingElseTrue();
        };

        var filtered = myEnumerable.Where(item =>
        item >= 1 ||
        item <= 200 ||
        validator(item) ||
        GetStuff(item).IsAllTrue() ||
        GetStuff(item).IsAllTrueExt()
        );
    }

    public static bool IsAllTrueExt(this HeavyResult hr)
    {
        { return hr.IsSomethingTrue() && hr.IsSomethingElseTrue(); }
    }

    public static HeavyResult GetStuff(int item)
    {
        return new HeavyResult(item);
    }

    public class HeavyResult
    {
        public HeavyResult(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        int Value { get; }

        public bool IsSomethingTrue()
        {
            { return Value >= 5; }
        }

        public bool IsSomethingElseTrue()
        {
            { return Value <= 50; }
        }

        public bool IsAllTrue()
        {
            { return IsSomethingTrue() && IsSomethingElseTrue(); }
        }

    }
}
```